# How to convert &str to JSON response?

Tags: json, rust

I have a `&str`:

```
{"index":0,"name":"AB/CDE/FG/402/test_int4","sts":"on","time":"2021-06-05 03:28:24.044284300 UTC","value":8}
```

How can I convert it to JSON?

```
{
"index": 0,
"name": "AB/CDE/FG/402/test_int4",
"sts": "on",
"time": "2021-06-05 03:28:24.044284300 UTC",
"value": 8 
}
```

is there anything like Python's `json.loads()` method available or something equivalent can be done in Rust?

Answer (score 9):

There's a misconception here. JSON is a *serialization* format, its always a string. Your two blocks are both JSON and functionally identical. What `json.loads()` is deserialize it into a *value* that can be accessed and manipulated natively.

You probably want to use a [`serde_json::Value`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/enum.Value.html) if you want this JSON to be used generically.

```
use serde_json::Value;

fn main() {
    let input = r#"{"index":0,"name":"AB/CDE/FG/402/test_int4","sts":"on","time":"2021-06-05 03:28:24.044284300 UTC","value":8}"#;
    let mut object: Value = serde_json::from_str(input).unwrap();
    
    if let Some(name) = object.get_mut("name") {
        *name = "new name".into();
    }
    
    println!("{}", object);
}
```

```
{"index":0,"name":"new name","sts":"on","time":"2021-06-05 03:28:24.044284300 UTC","value":8}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e4c7d3cb9baeceecfe5376d69135204c)

Or, its typical to create a structure that reflects what the JSON is expected to be and deserialize into that type via `serde`:

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Data {
    index: i32,
    name: String,
    sts: String,
    time: String,
    value: i32
}

fn main() {
    let input = r#"{"index":0,"name":"AB/CDE/FG/402/test_int4","sts":"on","time":"2021-06-05 03:28:24.044284300 UTC","value":8}"#;
    let mut object: Data = serde_json::from_str(input).unwrap();
    
    object.name = "new name".to_string();
    
    println!("{:#?}", object);
}
```

```
Data {
    index: 0,
    name: "new name",
    sts: "on",
    time: "2021-06-05 03:28:24.044284300 UTC",
    value: 8,
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1deedce855d27221193db270b8ce2071)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything built-in, but this package can do it:

```
use tinyjson::{JsonParseError, JsonValue};

fn main() -> Result<(), JsonParseError> {
   let s = r#"
{
   "index":0,
   "name":"AB/CDE/FG/402/test_int4",
   "sts":"on",
   "time":"2021-06-05 03:28:24.044284300 UTC",
   "value":8
}
"#;
   let m: JsonValue = s.parse()?;
   println!("{:?}", m);
   Ok(())
}
```

Result:

```
Object({
   "value": Number(8.0),
   "index": Number(0.0),
   "name": String("AB/CDE/FG/402/test_int4"),
   "time": String("2021-06-05 03:28:24.044284300 UTC"),
   "sts": String("on")
})
```

https://docs.rs/tinyjson