# How to convert a string to a valid json in rust

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am very new to rust with a background in javaScript and i am not able to go through a silly problem that this is *"How to JSON.parse in Rust?"*

I have a string `"{\"first\":\"one\",\"second\":\"two\"}"` which is a &str type, and i want an object `{first:"one",second:"two"}`.

I googled multiple links and am still stuck at this point.

tried approaches -

1. `let mut object: Value = serde_json::from_str(abc).unwrap();`

   error - the trait bound `api::Value: Deserialize<'_>` is not satisfied
2. converting it to string and Option by Some(string.as_deref())
3. [(Rust- JSON) How to convert &str to JSON response in rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67846025/rust-json-how-to-convert-str-to-json-response-in-rust)
4. https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-convert-a-string-type-to-a-json-object/72142

Comment: What is `api::Value`, where are your attempts (actual code, not just "I've tried this" because everything you linked has a solution to your problem)? You can checkout [mre] and [ask] for further tips how to improve your question.

Comment: Please provide the code of your approaches, 1) should definitely simply work.

Comment: It might be that `api::Value` is not what you wanted, probably `Value` is supposed to be `serde_json::Value`. Maybe your `use` statement is incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to parse a JSON string, but usually it does indeed involve [`serde`](https://serde.rs/) and [`serde_json`](https://docs.rs/serde_json).

If you just want a simple [`serde_json::Value`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/latest/serde_json/value/enum.Value.html) object, this works:

```rust
fn main() {
    let json_str = r#"{"first":"one","second":"two"}"#;
    let json_val: serde_json::Value = serde_json::from_str(json_str).unwrap();

    println!("{:#?}", json_val);
}
```

```
Object {
    "first": String("one"),
    "second": String("two"),
}
```

If you want something more sophisticated, like a struct that actually contains `first` and `second` members, you can parse it into a serde derived struct:

```rust
use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct MyValue {
    first: String,
    second: String,
}

fn main() {
    let json_str = r#"{"first":"one","second":"two"}"#;
    let my_value: MyValue = serde_json::from_str(json_str).unwrap();

    println!("{:#?}", my_value);
}
```

```
MyValue {
    first: "one",
    second: "two",
}
```

If you don't want a struct or `Value` at all and instead want a simple [`HashMap<String, String>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html), do this:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let json_str = r#"{"first":"one","second":"two"}"#;
    let my_dict: HashMap<String, String> = serde_json::from_str(json_str).unwrap();

    println!("{:#?}", my_dict);
}
```

```
{
    "first": "one",
    "second": "two",
}
```

The possibilities of `serde_json::from_str` are endless. Just figure out what tasks you want to perform with the data, and then choose the appropriate data type ;)

Answer (score 1):

The [JSONSchema parser macros](https://github.com/wvdveer/json_schema_parser) may help with creating the necessary structs if you have a JSONSchema for your JSON.

If you have example data, there are sites such as https://www.jsonschema.net/ that can create a JSONSchema from example data.